# access 2010 update tables with the most updated records

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a application in Access 2010 that is running in 3 different laptops creating jobs ticket everyday, in the morning they transfer all jobs already done in server to locally in the laptops, during the day they edit those jobs and finish some of them, at the end of the day each laptop must transfer all records back to server.

HERE IS THE PROBLEM, I want to update laptop 1 records to server which I am doing it ok, but when the second laptop start updating it changed all what laptop 1 did. So, I need to be able to update records in server taking in consideration the most updated ones in the laptops. In another words update the most recent records of the laptops to the server.

```
 UPDATE JobsOrder 
 INNER JOIN JobsOrder1 ON JobsOrder.Ticket = JobsOrder1.Ticket 
 SET 
    JobsOrder1.Location = [JobsOrder].[Location], 
    JobsOrder1.Supervisor = [JobsOrder].[Supervisor], 
    JobsOrder1.DigNumber = [JobsOrder].[DigNumber], 
    JobsOrder1.StartDigDate = [JobsOrder].[StartDigDate], 
    JobsOrder1.JobAddressNumber = [JobsOrder].[JobAddressNumber], 
    JobsOrder1.JobAddressName = [JobsOrder].[JobAddressName], 
    JobsOrder1.JobDescription = [JobsOrder].[JobDescription], 
    JobsOrder1.EmployeeName = [JobsOrder].[EmployeeName], 
    JobsOrder1.JobType = [JobsOrder].[JobType], 
    JobsOrder1.AssetID = [JobsOrder].[AssetID], 
    JobsOrder1.EmpoyeeID = [JobsOrder].[EmpoyeeID], 
    JobsOrder1.Notes = [JobsOrder].[Notes], 
    JobsOrder1.JobKind = [JobsOrder].[JobKind], 
    JobsOrder1.DateTimeTicketDone = [JobsOrder].[DateTimeTicketDone], 
    JobsOrder1.FINISH = [JobsOrder].[FINISH], 
    JobsOrder1.Priority = [JobsOrder].[Priority], 
    JobsOrder1.updateGIS = [JobsOrder].[updateGIS], 
    JobsOrder1.JobAddressTown = [JobsOrder].[JobAddressTown];
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field with a timestamp you set whenever a record is uppdated.

When updating, update only with those records where the timestamp is newer than the existing timestamp.